# asp.net MVC post data using jquery URL Redirection is not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm sending data PageA(Text boxes) to PageB using POST method and I've have Edit link in PageB. If  I click Edit link I want go back to PageA with my POST data. I'm able to POST the data using Jquery Post method but url redirection is not working. (I need to post data PageB to Page C also)

View: PageA

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerName", "PageB", FormMethod.Post))
    {
       //textboxes
    }
```

PageB:

```
<a>Edit</a>
 @using (Html.BeginForm("ControllerName", "PageC", FormMethod.Post))
        {
           //textboxes
        }
```

Jquery:

```
 $("a").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/ControllerName/PageA',
            type: 'POST',
            data: ModelData,
            contentType: "application/json",
            datatype: "html",
            success: function (data) {
                //window.location = "/ControllerName/PageA";

            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, request) {
                alert(XMLHttpRequest.responseText);
            }
        });

    });
```

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet]
    public Task<ViewResult>PageA()
        {
            Model model = new Model();

            return Task.FromResult<ViewResult>(View(model));

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public Task<ActionResult> PageA(Model model)
        {
            return Task.FromResult<ActionResult>(View(model));
            //return Task.FromResult<ActionResult>(RedirectToAction("PageA", model));

        }
```

If I use window.location = "/ControllerName/PageA"; it is redirecting to PageA but GET controller method is calling, at that time model is Empty.

Answer (score 0):

what you need to do is have an input on the get method and test for it

```
public Task<ViewResult> PageA(int editID = 0)
```

and then test for that.  If it isn't passed then load an empty page, if it is passed, use that ID to populate your model to send to the view.
Then make sure that you pass the id to be edited through your window.location

```
window.location = "@Url.Action("ControllerName", "PageA", new { editID = "id to be edited here" })";
```

Comment: url is redirecting but model is empty :(

Comment: are you seeing the id that you passed in your controller?